# Assign data to separate dataframes, combining and sort by year

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have `40` years of data so I was trying to assign each of them to a dataframe individually then store them all in a new dataframe, then sort them. Below is what i have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

year = 1976
count = 1

for i in range(0,40):

    df[count] = pd.read_excel('42003h'+str(year)+'.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

    count = count + 1
    year = 1976 + 1
```

I was given this error

> Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1

Any help would be appreciated please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create list of `Dataframes` `dfs` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) it to one `df` . `count` is not necessary. Last IIUC [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `year`:

```
import pandas as pd

year = 1976

dfs = []
for i in range(0,40):
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel('42003h'+str(year)+'.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1'))
    year += 1

#if need concat by columns        
#df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)   

#if need concat by rows
df = pd.concat(dfs)  

#if need sort by column `year`
df.sort_values(by='year', inplace=True)
```

Comment: this seems to only be giving me 1977 it actually starts at 1976 and goes straight up to 2015, then at the tail the date are no longer there its showing numbers like 1609 - 1613 and it should be sorted by index sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize your dictionary:

```
df = {}
for i in range(0,40):

    df[count] = pd.read_excel('42003h'+str(year)+'.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('42003h*.xlsx')

# if you want to merge your DFs horizontally then add: `axis=1` parameter
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True).sort_values('year')

count = len(files)
```

Comment: files seem to be empty but it should not be because the files are in the current directory

Comment: @renardo, try this instead: `files = glob.glob('42003h*.xlsx')`